# Why is MariaDB - or phpMyAdmin - rejecting my CREATE TABLE syntax for a Temporal Table?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a Syntax error, I don't know why?

[image]

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE appointments (
    AppId int(11)PRIMARY,
    docID int(11),
    patientID int(11),
    AppStart datetime,
    AppEnd datetime,
    PERIOD FOR p(AppStart,AppEnd),         /* <== Error on the `FOR`  keyword. */
    UNIQUE (docId, p WITHOUT OVERLAPS)     /* <== Error on the `UNIQUE`  keyword. */
)
```

Comment: **Exactly** what version of phpMyAdmin and MySQL are you running?

Comment: You're using the syntax for Application-versioned Temporal Tables, which is something that MariaDB **10.4.3** (and later) supports but (to my knowledge) MySQL **does not support**. So you'll need to either not use temporal tables, or install MariaDB instead of MySQL.

Comment: @Dai  Server version: 10.4.10-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: FWIW, I tried running your `CREATE TABLE` statment as-is in MariaDB 10.6 and I get a syntax error too, except it's on the `PRIMARY` keyword. If you change it to `PRIMARY KEY` then the operation succeeds and the table is created.

Comment: I know that phpMyAdmin is ostensibly a thin front-end for MySQL which _should_ work with MariaDB, I don't know if phpMyAdmin's SQL editor implements its own parser/validator or if it's always just a frontend for the server's SQL engine.

Comment: @Dai  would it work if I Update it to MariaDB 10.6?

Comment: First see what happens when you use `PRIMARY KEY` instead?

Comment: @Dai actually, nothing has changed, the same error

Comment: Can you use MariaDB's in-box (built-in) command-line client program, at least to test it?

Comment: @Dai II don't know how to do that? But have you tried it in phpMyAdmin? and did it work?

Comment: I don’t have a PHP environment to test with, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

based on my own repro (in MariaDB 10.6, not your version 10.4.10) the syntax-error highlights do not correspond to the **actual** syntax error which is that you need to put `PRIMARY KEY` instead of just `PRIMARY`.

So run this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE appointments (
    AppId     int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
    docID     int(11),
    patientID int(11),
    AppStart  datetime,
    AppEnd    datetime,
    PERIOD FOR p(AppStart,AppEnd),
    UNIQUE (docId, p WITHOUT OVERLAPS)
)
```

Screenshot proof:

[image]